# Pyside Qcolor Dialog, sender object name

Tags: python, pyside6

Hi I'm learning pyside 6, and I was trying to pass the sender object name to _color_selected() to modify the stylesheet of the sender, but I cant find a solution on how to pass the sender to the _color_selected function.

## QPushButton

```
# Body Color up
self._body_color_up = QPushButton(self)
self._body_color_up.setObjectName('_body_color_up')
self._body_color_up.setFixedHeight(25)
self._body_color_up.setFixedWidth(25)
self._body_color_up.setStyleSheet(stylesheet.button_color_selector)
self._body_color_up.clicked.connect(self._open_color_dialog)
```

## Open color dialog function

```
def _open_color_dialog(self):
    self.dialog = QColorDialog()
    sender = self.sender()
    sender_obj = sender.objectName()
    self.dialog.colorSelected.connect(self._color_selected())
    self.dialog.show()
    
    
@Slot()
def _color_selected(self, color):
    self.sender_obj.setStyleSheet("background-color:%s;" % color.name())
```

Comment: Note that if you just use the blocking `exec()` of the dialog, you can avoid connecting it, and just get the selected color after its execution.

Comment: Im going to copy this here since it was a better suggestion than my idea...  The sender always refers to the last QObject that emitted the last signal. Add a button argument in the function: def _color_selected(self, button, color): then just self.dialog.colorSelected.connect(lambda color: self._color_selected(sender, color)) – 
musicamante
 18 mins ago

Comment: Thanks, I make it work. Again thanks a lot, I was struggling with this a lot.